# the fake link in website gets redirected to homepage

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

The fake link in website gets redirected to homepage, but I want it to redirect to 404 error page. I have tried everything but the redirect occurs to home page.

Inside `htaccess.txt` I added following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=16 in the root
```

Also in templates/root folder `error.php` I added following:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
    header('Location:/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=16');
        exit;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is actually an article with the ID of 16. If you simply want to test the 404 error page, then in the URL, use `com_contents` (with an `s` on the end)

Comment: redirects to home page

Comment: In which case you have a rule somewhere that is redirecting all 404's to the homepage. Check the Redirect Manager in the Joomla backend and ensure there is nothing untoward in the htaccess file

Comment: Check the Redirect Manager in the Joomla backend?

Comment: Joomla admin backend >> Components (top menu) >> Redirect

Comment: it has but both are unpublished

Comment: Ok, and are there any custom redirect rules for 404 errors in your htaccess file? Or do you have any 3rd party plugins that might be causing this?

Comment: there were no rules to redirect so i just wrote  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=16 in the root